# Is there a numpy function that returns a matrix of indexs of an array in given size?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 28x28 numpy array and I want to create a new numpy array of tuples, each tuple represents an index in the original array, something like:
[(0, 0), (0, 1), ..., (0, 28),
 (1, 0), (1, 1),..., (1, 28),... and so on.

Is there a simple way of doing it?

Answer (score 4):

There is [`np.ndindex`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html), which you can use to iterate over the N-dimensional indices given the shape of an array:

```
a = np.random.rand(28,28)

list(np.ndindex(a.shape))
# [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0,...
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition `np.ndindex()` (which is the simplest in this case), you can use [`np.unravel_index()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) and [`np.ravel_multi_index()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html) to go back and forth from a linear and a multi-index.

For example:

```
import numpy as np


shape = (3, 5)
arr = np.random.rand(*shape)
print([np.unravel_index(i, shape) for i in range(np.prod(shape))])
# [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, since you want a list of tuples, you could also consider not actually using NumPy:

```py
from itertools import product

a = ...  # Your array
idx_tuples = product(*map(range, a.shape))
```

Then `list(idx_tuples)` would give you the list that you want. This will probably be slower, the only rather minor advantage is that, if you only needed that list to iterate it once, you can do `for idx in idx_tuples:` to generate the tuples as you iterate, saving the memory of creating them all in advance.